# query to find the records between two tables for a given date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a employee table which holds the information about which department the employee belongs during a period of time. At any point in a time a employee can belong to only one department. The end date column holds till what date the employee had stayed in a particular department. if the end date column holds a future date which means thats the latest department for a employee.

| empid | deptname | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sales | jan-20-2022 | jan-24-2022 |
| 1 | marketing | jan-25-2022 | feb-03-2022 |
| 1 | support | feb-04-2022 | feb-06-2022 |
| 1 | training | feb-07-2022 | dec-31-2050 |

I have a call details table which holds the information of which employee took the call and what is call start time and call end time.

| call_id | empid | callstart_time | callendtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | jan-21-2022 10:00:00 | jan-21-2022 10:30:00 |
| 11 | 1 | jan-21-2022 10:40:00 | jan-21-2022 10:45:00 |
| 12 | 1 | feb-01-2022 11:20:00 | feb-01-2022 11:30:00 |
| 13 | 1 | feb-05-2022 09:00:00 | feb-05-2022 10:00:00 |
| 14 | 1 | feb-08-2022 10:00:00 | feb-08-2022 11:00:00 |

Now my question is:

I am looking for inputs and the sample query where i need to know what was the employees department during the time the employee took the call.

For example, if I want to know what are the calls took by an employee from jan-20-2022 to feb-02-2022 and what was there department name during the time of the call. i need the below output.

| call_id | empid | callstart_time | callendtime | deptname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | jan-21-2022 10:00:00 | jan-21-2022 10:30:00 | sales |
| 11 | 1 | jan-21-2022 10:40:00 | jan-21-2022 10:45:00 | sales |
| 12 | 1 | feb-01-2022 11:20:00 | feb-01-2022 11:30:00 | marketing |

If i run the query for a date range from feb-04-2022 to feb-10-2022, i want to see the below output

| call_id | empid | callstart_time | callendtime | deptname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 1 | feb-05-2022 09:00:00 | feb-05-2022 10:00:00 | support |
| 14 | 1 | feb-08-2022 10:00:00 | feb-08-2022 11:00:00 | training |

please share few inputs on how to achieve this output using the sql query

Comment: Please avoid pictures that made it hard to solve your issue. In addition, that data(figure) for the call detail table does not exist.

Comment: @RF1991 I have updated the question with the data tables. i hope its easy to understand the data set now

Comment: please share the create table and insert data scripts for the above sample data.

Comment: Also, which dbms are you using, Oracle or SQL Server? It's important to post the DDL (Create Table statements) and DML (Insert  into statements for sample data above) as the datatypes and values can impact the query needed to produce the desired results. Use a site like https://dbfiddle.uk/ to create an example. Then click the "markdown" link to generate nicely formatted sql code you can paste into your question html.

Comment: Another great tool for creating DDL + DML statements is http://sqlfiddle.com/. Just click the "Text to DDL" button and paste the tables from above (including headers) and it generates this lovely fiddle for you automatically: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18

Answer (score 2):

A `CROSS APPLY` lets you define a subselect to pick the applicable employee record. In your case, the latest employee record prior to the call. Something like:

```
SELECT C.*, E.deptname
FROM calldetails C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM employee E
    WHERE E.empid = C.empid
    AND E.startdate <= C.callstart_time
    ORDER BY E.startdate DESC
) E
ORDER BY C.callstart_time
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26208840c3c574d5a96059034884daa4)

Or since you have end date, a simple join will do

```
SELECT C.*, E.deptname
FROM calldetails C
JOIN employee E
    ON E.empid = C.empid
    AND E.startdate <= C.callstart_time
    AND E.enddate > DATEADD(day, -1, C.callstart_time)
ORDER BY C.callstart_time
```

Note the date adjustment needed for the enddate comparison. This is needed because you are using inclusive enddates, Using exclusive end dates (where enddate = startdate for the next record works much better for range checks and calculations.

Comment: Go with the JOIN.  Once you get beyond a few sample rows, CROSS APPLY is measurably more expensive in terms of IO and time.